# Pre-process data file before pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, fixed-length-record

I work with data output from SAP, but it is neither CSV, as it does not quote strings containing its delimiter, nor fixed width as it has multi-byte chars. It is kind of a "fixed width" character-wise.

To get it into pandas I currently read the file, get the delimiters position, slice every line around the delimiters and then save it to a proper CSV which I can read without trouble.

I see that pandas read_csv can get a file buffer. How would I pass my stream straight to it, without saving a csv file? Should I make a generator? Can I get csv.writer.writerow output without giving it a file handle?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

caminho= r'C:\Users\user\Documents\SAP\Tests\\'
arquivo = "ExpComp_01.txt"
tipo_dado = {"KEY_GUID":"object", "DEL_IND":"object", "HDR_GUID":"object", , "PRICE":"object", "LEADTIME":"int16", "MANUFACTURER":"object", "LOAD_TIME":"object", "APPR_TIME":"object", "SEND_TIME":"object", "DESCRIPTION":"object"} 

def desmembra(linha, limites):
    # This functions receives each delimiter's index and cuts around it
    posicao=limites[0]    
    for limite in limites[1:]:
        yield linha[posicao+1:limite]
        posicao=limite

def pre_processa(arquivo):
    import csv
    import os
    # Translates SAP output in standard CSV
    with open(arquivo,"r", encoding="mbcs") as entrada, open(arquivo[:-3] +
    "csv", "w", newline="", encoding="mbcs") as saida:
        escreve=csv.writer(saida,csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter=";").writerow
        for line in entrada:
            # Find heading
            if line[0]=="|":
                delimitadores = [x for x, v in enumerate(line) if v == '|']
                if line[-2] != "|": 
                    delimitadores.append(None)
                cabecalho_teste=line[:50]
                escreve([campo.strip() for campo in desmembra(line,delimitadores)])
                break
        for line in entrada:
            if line[0]=="|" and line[:50]!=cabecalho_teste:
                escreve([campo.strip() for campo in desmembra(line, delimitadores)])

pre_processa(caminho+arquivo)       
dados = pd.read_csv(caminho + arquivo[:-3] + "csv", sep=";",
                    header=0, encoding="mbcs", dtype=tipo_dado)
```

---

Also, if you could share best practices:
I have odd datetime strings as this `20.120.813.132.432` which I can successfully convert using

```
dados["SEND_TIME"]=pd.to_datetime(dados["SEND_TIME"], format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
dados["SEND_TIME"].replace(regex=False,inplace=True,to_replace=r'.',value=r'')
```

I can't write a parser for it because I have dates stored in different string formats. Would it be faster to specify a converter to do it during import or have pandas do it column-wise in the end?
I have a similar issue with a code `99999999` that I have to add dots to `99.999.999`. I do not know if I **should write a converter or wait until after the import to do a `df.replace`**

**EDIT** -- Sample data:

---

```
|                        KEY_GUID|DEL_IND|                        HDR_GUID|Prod_CD |DESCRIPTION                      |      PRICE|LEADTIME|MANUFACTURER|          LOAD_TIME|APPR_TIME     |          SEND_TIME|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|000427507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123636|Vneráéíoaeot.sadot.m             |     29,55 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.157 |
|000527507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123643|Tnerasodaeot|sadot.m             |    122,91 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.141 |
|0005DB50112F9E69E10000000A1D2028|       |384BB350BF56315DE20062700D627978|75123676|Dnerasodáeot.sadot.m             |252.446,99 |3       |POLAND      |20.121.226.175.640 |20121226183608|20.121.222.000.015 |
|000627507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123652|Pner|sodaeot.sadot.m             |    657,49 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.128 |
|000727507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|        |Rnerasodaeot.sadot.m             |    523,63 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.707.010.119 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                        KEY_GUID|DEL_IND|                        HDR_GUID|Prod_CD |DESCRIPTION                      |      PRICE|LEADTIME|MANUFACTURER|          LOAD_TIME|APPR_TIME     |          SEND_TIME|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   |000827507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123603|Inerasodéeot.sadot.m             |  2.073,63 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.127 |
|000927507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123662|Ane|asodaeot.sadot.m             |      0,22 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.135 |
|000A27507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123626|Pneraíodaeot.sadot.m             |    300,75 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.140 |
|000B27507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|        |Aneraéodaeot.sadot.m             |      1,19 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.131 |
|000C27507E64FB29E2006281548EB186|       |4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83|75123613|Cnerasodaeot.sadot.m             |     30,90 |30      |            |20.120.813.132.432 |20120813132929|20.120.505.010.144 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would be dealing with other tables with other fields. All in this general form. I can only trust the separators in the heading. Also I may have repeated headings in the data. It looks like a matricial printout.

Comment: Can you post sample raw data, also there is a `read_fwf` function but it doesn't have as many tweaks as `read_csv`

Comment: Added sample data. I read that `read_fwf` is not as fast. Since I have some million records to work with at each cycle, I did not try that. I also have had A LOT of trouble treating this as fixed width when I actually have this multi-byte characters I put in the sample. My first try was using `struct.unpack`. This preprocessing is actually fast, but I would like to avoid saving a new bridge file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build a DataFrame without first writing to a CSV, then you don't
need `pd.read_csv`. While it is possible to use `io.BytesIO` or
`cString.StringIO` to write to an in-memory file-like object, it doesn't make
sense to convert an iterable of values (like `desmembra(line, delimitadores)`)
to a single string just to re-parse it with `pd.read_csv`.

Instead, it is more direct to use `pd.DataFrame`, since `pd.DataFrame` can accept an iterator of row data.

Operating on values one-by-one using plain Python is usually not the fastest way to go. Generally, using Pandas functions on whole columns is faster. Therefore, I would parse `arquivo` into a DataFrame of strings first, and then use Pandas functions to post-process the columns into the correct dtype and values.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import io

caminho = r'C:\Users\u5en\Documents\SAP\Testes\\'
arquivo = os.path.join(caminho, "ExpComp_01.txt")
arquivo_csv = os.path.splitext(arquivo)[0] + '.csv'

def desmembra(linha, limites):
    # This functions receives each delimiter's index and cuts around it
    return [linha[limites[i]+1:limites[i+1]].strip()
            for i in range(len(limites[:-1]))]

def pre_processa(arquivo, enc):
    # Translates SAP output into an iterator of lists of strings
    with io.open(arquivo, "r", encoding=enc) as entrada:
        for line in entrada:
            # Find heading
            if line[0] == "|":
                delimitadores = [x for x, v in enumerate(line) if v == '|']
                if line[-2] != "|": 
                    delimitadores.append(None)
                cabecalho_teste = line[:50]
                yield desmembra(line, delimitadores)
                break
        for line in entrada:
            if line[0] == "|" and line[:50] != cabecalho_teste:
                yield desmembra(line, delimitadores)                

def post_process(dados):
    dados['LEADTIME'] = dados['LEADTIME'].astype('int16')
    for col in ('SEND_TIME', 'LOAD_TIME', 'PRICE'):
        dados[col] = dados[col].str.replace(r'.', '')
    for col in ('SEND_TIME', 'LOAD_TIME', 'APPR_TIME'):
        dados[col] = pd.to_datetime(dados[col], format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    return dados

enc = 'mbcs'  
saida = pre_processa(arquivo, enc)
header = next(saida)
dados = pd.DataFrame(saida, columns=header)
dados = post_process(dados)
print(dados)
```

yields

```
                           KEY_GUID DEL_IND                          HDR_GUID  \
0  000427507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
1  000527507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
2  0005DB50112F9E69E10000000A1D2028          384BB350BF56315DE20062700D627978   
3  000627507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
4  000727507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
5  000927507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
6  000A27507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
7  000B27507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   
8  000C27507E64FB29E2006281548EB186          4C1AD7E25DC50D61E10000000A19FF83   

    Prod_CD           DESCRIPTION      PRICE  LEADTIME MANUFACTURER  \
0  75123636  Vneráéíoaeot.sadot.m      29,55        30                
1  75123643  Tnerasodaeot|sadot.m     122,91        30                
2  75123676  Dnerasodáeot.sadot.m  252446,99         3       POLAND   
3  75123652  Pner|sodaeot.sadot.m     657,49        30                
4            Rnerasodaeot.sadot.m     523,63        30                
5  75123662  Ane|asodaeot.sadot.m       0,22        30                
6  75123626  Pneraíodaeot.sadot.m     300,75        30                
7            Aneraéodaeot.sadot.m       1,19        30                
8  75123613  Cnerasodaeot.sadot.m      30,90        30                

            LOAD_TIME           APPR_TIME           SEND_TIME  
0 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:57  
1 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:41  
2 2012-12-26 17:56:40 2012-12-26 18:36:08 2012-12-22 00:00:15  
3 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:28  
4 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-07-07 01:01:19  
5 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:35  
6 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:40  
7 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:31  
8 2012-08-13 13:24:32 2012-08-13 13:29:29 2012-05-05 01:01:44
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was just now trying to do it with StringIO as you advised not to. :P I won't then. I thought the same as you on applying functions to columns, I just gave a second though as it has the converters dict functionality. It would have no point than. Thanks for the overall improvement! That part you commented was for when the line overflows and there is no "|" to end the line. It got chopped off, but I will edit it now.

Comment: Although `pd.read_csv` has the potentially useful `converters` parameter, calling a Python function once for each value in a million-plus records CSV is likely to take a considerable amount of time. While post-processing with `astype` and [vectorized string functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods) will take some time too, it is likely to be faster.

Comment: should I really `encode` in `desmembra`? Then i get a dataframe of bytes and when using `DataFrame.to_csv` it writes out byte strings `repr` in the file as _u'some_string'_. I could take that out and work with unicode internally, but I was wondering if there was any rationale behind that `encode`. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sorry; that was a mistake on my part. Generally, you *should* work with unicode internally and encode only on output. Thanks for the correction.